# How to add file-picker library to an android application

Tags: android, filepicker.io

[Filepicker](https://www.inkfilepicker.com/) just asks to drop in the library (which is on [github](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-android)) in the project and call up the activities, but the library itself contains a Manifest file and its own resource files!!

I am using AndroidStudio. How should I go about including this in my project?

Answer (score 2):

For Android library projects it is totally fine to contain manifest file and resources (check it out at [developers portal](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)).

To see how it works, you can download and run the [sample app](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-android/tree/master/sample-studio))

And finally, to add it to your own app follow the filepicker's README.

Cheers,